# Child Class to Base Class Conversion Issue

Tags: c++, virtual

I have declared a Super Class with a virtual print function and Child class inherits Super class. I have created an instance of Child Class and assigned to Super Class in 2 different ways.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Super
{
public:
    Super(){}
    virtual void print()
    {
    cout << "Super class is printing " << endl;
    }
};

class Child: public Super
{
public:
    Child(){}
    void print()
    {
        cout << "Child class printing" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    Super s = c;
    Super &ss = c;
    s.print(); //prints "Super Class is printing
    ss.print(); //prints "Child Class is printing
    return 0;
}
```

Why we do not get same output from these two print calls ? How does adding reference change the behavior?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Object slicing issue:

If you take a super class and assign it the value of a subclass only the members that are part of the super class get copied over  (default assignment operator behavior).

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Super {
public:
   int a;
   Super(): a(0) { }
   Super(int _a): a(_a) { }
   virtual void dump() {
        cout << "A is : " << a << std::endl;
   }
};

class Child: public Super {
public: 
   int b;

   Child(int _a, int _b): b(_b), Super(_a) { } 
   virtual void dump() {
        Super::dump();
        cout << "B is : " << b << std::endl;
   }

};

int main() {
    Child c(5, 10);
    Super s;
    s.dump();  // A is 0
    s = c;
    s.dump();  // A is 5 (but there is no B in s 
               // so calling Child::dump would be nonsensical
}
```

So as you can see that calling the child `dump` is nonsensical when the child value is assigned to the parent; because there is no "b" in the parent context.

Note that a statement like:
        c = s;

is non-sensical because while parentage is deterministic (Child is the type of Super so the implicit operator `Super& Super::operator=(const Super&)` applies to the derived `Child` class the reverse isn't true; i.e. `Child& Child::operator=(const Child&)` does not make sense in context of `Super`

### The reference issue

Okay so the confusion comes in from understanding what a reference variable is.  A reference variable is a synonym for whatever it is *initialized* with.  You can use the reference variable exactly like the original.

In your case:

```
   ss.print();
```

is the same as

```
   c.print();
```

"
To see this more explicitly, consider the following snippet:

```
int foo;
int& bar = foo;

// bar is now a reference to foo so the following will sets foo to 67
bar = 67;
std::cout << foo <<std::endl;
```

Comment: *A bit pedantic*: "A reference variable is a synonym for whatever is assigned to it" No, *for whatever you initialized it with*. It has nothing to do with an actual *assignment*, even though it may use a `=` like in your example. Some other ways to initialize a reference: `int& bar{foo};` (C++11) and `int& bar(foo)`.

Comment: An even better term for the process of creating a reference is *binding*, and then one can talk about the object it is *bound to*.

Comment: @DyP Nuanced :-) I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic *and* static type of `s` is `Super` but the assignment from `c` makes a copy of the `Super` subobject from inside `c` and `s` always behaves as a `Super`.

However, `ss` has a static type of `Super`, but its dynamic type depends on its initialisation, which in this case is `Child`, so the virtual dispatch behaves accordingly.

This phenomenon is called ["object slicing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)